# Where was Jesus's soul during the three days of His death?

Tags: catholicism, resurrection-of-jesus

There is a three day period between Jesus's death and resurrection. Where does the Catholic Church teach Jesus's soul was during that time?

Comment: How can a body be in a "spiritual state"? That's analogous to asking: "What corporal state was the soul…?"

Comment: @Geremia I was speaking in broad terms about the location and actions of Jesus' soul, as elaborated on in the actual body of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explaining the second part of the [fourth article of the Creed](http://www.catholicapologetics.info/thechurch/catechism/ApostlesCreed04.shtml) ("Died and Buried"), the [*Catechism of the Council of Trent*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=5864) says:

> man dies when the soul is separated from the body. When, therefore, we say that Jesus died, we mean that His soul was disunited from His body. We do not admit, however, that the Divinity was separated from His body. On the contrary, we firmly believe and profess that when His soul was dissociated from His body, His Divinity continued always united both to His body in the sepulchre and to His soul in [[the] limbo [of the Fathers, "Abraham's Bosom"]](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/41251/1787).